# Powershell code block for non standard exit

Tags: powershell, exit, terminate

I have a script which takes data from Active Directory, creates Excel workbook out of them and then makes the Excel window visible. The problem is with non standard exits (error, ctrl+c during the execution of script, etc.) - the Excel instance does not terminate and is not visible.

*Which code block can be used to force termination of the Excel instance (stored in a variable) upon non standard exit?* 
Try/catch/finally did not help, because finally would also terminate Excel upon standard exit. I think begin/process/end would have the same problem.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I do _not_ want it to close upon standard run - the workbook should stay open.

Comment: `$EverythingAlright = $false; try { …; $EverythingAlright = $true } finally { if(!$EverythingAlright) { … } }`

Comment: Yup, also thought of this way, but it looks heavy handed to me, thought there would be a better way to do that?

Comment: What would be heavy handed about it if the finally block is exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: An extra variable with an extra if condition, I was wondering if it was not possible to do it in a more elegant way.